# sending json data to server in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my application i have to integrate API. I am not getting code for how to check whether internet is available or not. How to send JSON Data to server. Please help me out. As in android we call API in AsyncTask class. In blackberry i did not found like this.

Suggest me some link or ideas so that i can integrate code. I am googling. But did not getting result .
 What I have tried is here:

```
 JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
 postData.put("userId", "24");
 postData.put("messageTime","06:00:00");
 postData.put("language", language[lang_Ocf.getSelectedIndex()]);
 System.out.println("********json********"+postData);

 ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
 ConnectionDescriptor conDesc = null;
 try
 {
    conDesc = conFactory.getConnection(url+";deviceside=true");
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println(e.toString()+":"+e.getMessage());
 }

 String response = ""; // this variable used for the server response
 // if we can get the connection descriptor from ConnectionFactory
 if(null != conDesc)
 {
    try
    {
       HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)conDesc.getConnection();
       //set the header property
       connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length())); 
       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
       OutputStream out = connection.openOutputStream();
       out.write(postData.get);
       out.flush();
       out.close();
       int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
       if(responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){

          InputStream in = connection.openInputStream();
          StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
          int read = -1;
          while((read = in.read())!= -1)
             buf.append((char)read);

          response = buf.toString();
       }
       Dialog.inform(response);

       connection.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
 }

 return response;
```

Thanks

Comment: what is **not** working about the code above?

Comment: @Nate: Thanks. I was running code over simulator and i did not select Launch Mobile Data system connection, its working. Now Problem is i have implement various api on different screen. now i am copying this same code, while running it is giving me error Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Packaging project HelaBibleWhereUR failed (took 10.715 seconds) 
I create new simple class and put POST function(String url) in new class, it is giving me same error. Suggest me something pls

Comment: It looks like you solved your problem.  If you still want something that functions like the `AsyncTask` in Android, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13010227/119114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

Error:

> Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Packaging project HelaBibleWhereUR failed (took 10.715 seconds)

I simply put jar.exe that is under java bin folder in the jre bin folder.