# BlackBerry multithreading

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me

I want to know about the threading concept in BlackBerry.

In Android we have async task or handlers to communicate. Is there something similar available in BlackBerry? How do two threads communicate? How do you pass data from a background thread to the UI thread?

Comment: See [this blackberry document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Event_thread_1593335_11.jsp), maybe [this one, too](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808), and my [answer to a question about "porting" AsyncTask to Blackberry Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13010227/119114)

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency is not a trivial thing. It's really difficult to craft a Thread-safe solution. In Blackberry Java the situation is even worse, as only JavaME Threading APIs are available, meaning you can't use all the Java SE high level classes (like executors, locks, collections, etc).

My advice would be not to try to port Android's `AsyncTask` or any other high level concurrency-related class on your own, since very likely you'll make mistakes (unless you are well versed in concurrent programming). I myself would avoid it as much as possible. Instead keep the concurrent code as simple and small as you can. Most of the times all you need is to refresh the GUI from a worker thread. This can be done easily with `UiApplication.invokeLater` and `UiApplication.invokeAndWait`, and you don't need to write concurrent code at all.

If you want to learn more about concurrency, I'd start with [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) by Oracle. It's aimed for JavaSE, but almost the first half is useful for JavaME as well. In case you want to learn more advanced concurrent programming, [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is a must read.

Comment: Most real BB apps don't restrict themselves to the orig Java SE core.