# How to get data from localhost server using Blackberry Simulator

Tags: php, json, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to get data from server localhost using Blackberry simulator. My server give data into JSON file. How I can to display the data in Blackberry simulator and how to parse JSON into String.
I wish some one help me.

This is my source code for server.

```
<?php
    require('db.php');
    $query="select*from penarikan";
    $hasil=mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($hasil)>0)
    {
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
        {
            $x[]=$data;
        }

    }
    echo(json_encode($x));
?>
```

and this is my source code for Blackberry

```
package com.irwan.bb.pa;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import org.json.me.JSONObject;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class ScreenViewPenarikan extends MainScreen {
    HttpConnection httpconnection;
    InputStream inputStream;


    public ScreenViewPenarikan() {
        super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        runJson();
    }

    public void runJson()
    {
        try {

            String url="http://127.0.0.1:80/proyek_akhir/view_penarikan.php;deviceside=true";
            System.out.println(url);

            //connect to server
            httpconnection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            inputStream=httpconnection.openDataInputStream();

            if(httpconnection.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                //add(new LabelField("Ada konesksi"));
                InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
                int readCharacter;
                StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((readCharacter = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    responseBuffer.append((char) readCharacter);
                    httpconnection.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    reader.close();
                    String responseMessage = new String(responseBuffer);
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseMessage);
                    add(new LabelField(object));


                }
            }
            else{
                //add(new LabelField("Koneksi tidak ada"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you getting response from server ?

Comment: yes, I get response from server.

Comment: what is the format of that response ?

Comment: I want to catch data from server, server give data into JSON file. but I can't catch it in Blackberry simulator. How can I catch data from the server?

Comment: JSON file or JSON String ?

Comment: will you show the value in responseMessage  ?

Comment: [{"0":"1","id_penarikan":"1","1":"2","jlh_nominal":"2","2":"2013-06-30","tanggal":"2013-06-30","3":"30110089","no_rekening":"30110089"}]

Comment: when I run the server, this JSON are display. so I will catch the JSON in Blackberry Simulator.

Comment: @Irwan, you are performing your network request on the main (UI) thread, which is not a good idea.  I suggest moving this onto a background thread, and then using `UiApplication#invokeLater()` to display the results back on the UI thread.  Or, if you're familiar with Android's AsyncTask class, you could [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13010227/119114).

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```json
[
    {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "2",
        "2": "2013-06-30",
        "3": "30110089",
        "id_penarikan": "1",
        "jlh_nominal": "2",
        "tanggal‌": "2013-06-30",
        "no_rekening": "30110089"
    }
]
```

and

```java
  while ((readCharacter = reader.read()) != -1) {
     responseBuffer.append((char) readCharacter);
  }

  String val="";
  String responseMessage = new String(responseBuffer);
  JSONArray j=new JSONArray(responseMessage);
  JSONObject j0=j.getJSONObject(0);
  val=j0.getString("id_penarikan");
  add(new LabelField(val));
```

Comment: I haved tried, but this notification appear A JSONArray must start with '[' at character 0 of

Comment: when I tried, this notification appear App Error 104 Uncaught JSONException.

Comment: Are you calling `Dialog.alert()` anywhere? This error usually occurs when `Dialog.alert()` is used outside of the event thread or on a UI update code.